# WCF duplex service, clients dropped when service restarted

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service which is hosted in a Windows Service.
There are multiple clients who subscribe to the service.
When I restart the service, these connections are lost. 
How can I persist the list of subscribers and get the clients to reconnect when the service starts again. 
Are there any examples that I could look at for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the clients responsibility to pick up the failed connection when the server restarts or indeed for any other connection drop.  One way to do this is just to reconstruct your proxy object - as you did for the initial connection.  Server side you could persist your client list and on restart check/trace if any clients fail to reconnect after a fixed time or on polling timer but this would require that your server hodls a unique and persistant id from the clients (ie that doesn't change when client reconnects).

Comment: So should the client poll the service periodically and reconnect if required?

Comment: Yes - the client can just have a fixed timer delay before next connection attempt if a connection attempt fails.